# Bad sides of Scala Cake Pattern as dependencies injection

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, dependency-management

Let's see the following very simple cake pattern example:

```
trait PrintSomething{

  def printSomeThing(s:String):Unit
}

trait PrintSomethingToConsole extends PrintSomething{

  override def printSomeThing(s: String): Unit = println("Print To Console!!!")
}

trait PrintSomethingToLog extends PrintSomething{

  override def printSomeThing(s: String): Unit = println("Print To Log!!!")
}

class MyAction{

  self:PrintSomething =>

  printSomeThing("This is it")
}

new MyAction with PrintSomethingToConsole
new MyAction with PrintSomethingToLog
```

I see in some blogs that the bad side of this pattern is breaking 
`Open-Close Principle` and `Interface Segregation Principle`.

As far as I understand, there is a possibility to override `printSomething` method inside MyAction and modify functionality with no matter which `PrintSomething` trait was injected:

```
class MyAction{
    self:PrintSomething =>

    override def printSomeThing(s: String): Unit = println("I just Broke Open-Close Principle!!!!! ")
  }
```

Am I right?

However I don't understand how I can violate `Interface Segregation Principle` here. Can someone elaborate?

Comment: `printSomeThing` in `PrintSomething` is abstract, so you do not need that `override` in `PrintSomethingToConsole` or `PrintSomethingToLog`. You are not overriding the existing implementation, because there isn't one!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any conflict with the open-closed principle. All your classes and traits are open for extension and closed for modification. And since they only have a single method, the interface segregation principle doesn't really apply!

Even if you override `printSomeThing` in your `MyAction` class, you have still not violated either principle. All the objects remain open for extension (you can extend them) and closed for modification (you can not change their behaviour). An instance of `PrintSomethingToLog` will always print to the log; you cannot modify it to print to the console.

An instance of `PrintSomething` may have different implementations of `printSomeThing` but this is just polymorphism via inheritance; it does not mean that `PrintSomething` is open for modification because `PrintSomething` is an interface, not a concrete class, and you can't change the interface.